Algorithm of computing the x^m term of $\prod_{i=1}^n (1+x^{a_i}) mod p$
I'm wondering of algorithms computing the $x^m$  term of $\prod_{i=1}^n (1+x^{a_i}) \mod p$, where $p$ is a SMALL prime(like 2,3,5,etc.), and $a_i$ are positive integers. $\sum{a_i}\le t,$ but $t$ may be large.
Obviously the function is the generating function of the subset sum problem. For LARGE prime p, we may compute the numerical log of each factor in $O(t\log t)$ time, make addition of the logarithms, and the compute the exponential using FFT's. However for small p's, the Taylor series of exponential has n! as dominator, which becomes total nonsense module p.
Now I come up with two ways trying to overcome these difficulties:

Instead of computing the logarithm, we may compute the differentiation of logarithm (f'/f), and solve the equation f'(x)=f(x)g(x)(mod p), but f isn't unique. They can vary a $(h(x))^p$ factor.
Do the calculation in p-adic field, but high precision is needed due to $v_p(n!)$ is large. The overall time complexity is worse with consideration of precision.

Do you know any of the relevant papers or works?
